# Disabling Internet Explorer thru Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

Trying to disable Internet Explorer but is receiving a prompt whether to complete the operation now? [Y/N]?

Tried this command:

Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 -Online -Confirm:$false

Tried this command:

Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 -Online -Confirm:$false

But received an error message:

[image]

Comment: There is no `-Confirm` there, you're looking for `-NoRestart`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the suggestion given by Santiago.

The correct command to disable the Internet Explorer using the Powershell is as below.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName internet-explorer-optional-amd64
```

When you run the command, it will ask you whether you would like to restart the machine or later. You could enter the desired choice.

[image]

**Note:** Make sure you are running the Powershell as Administrator.